# Base64 svg on ie11 not rendering when resized

Tags: html, svg, base64, internet-explorer-11

I have a particular *svg* file encoded in *base64* that I'm trying to display with an `img` tag.

My problem is; for **this particular svg only** the image is not rendered when resized on **internet explorer only**

You can try it yourself (I'm on windows7 with ie11): [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EEpJMR)

Do you have any explanation/workaround for this ?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look very close when playing with the size, we can see parts of the SVG are actually displayed. It seems that IE resizes the canvas but not the actual shape.

Decoding your SVG file, here is what we get:

```
<svg height="361.5" width="361.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m-110.25-20.25h582v402h-582z" fill="none"/>...</svg>
```

The `height` and `width` are fixed. Changing these properties with a `viewBox` property like this allows IE to resize the shape:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 361.5 361.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m-110.25-20.25h582v402h-582z" fill="none"/>...</svg>
```

Kind regards!